# errno::eacces: permission denied @ rb_sysopen when uploading jpg

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, file-upload

I am developing rails app and I have problem when I try to upload photo to a server, error message is shown. In log file I have error: "Errno::EACCES (Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /photo.jpg". Issue occurred on line "File.open(...)"

My upload method:

```
def upload_photo
    logger.info(params.to_s)
    logger.info(params[:file].to_s)
    photo = params[:file]
    filename = photo.instance_variable_get(:@headers).to_s.match(/filename="(.*)"/).captures[0]
        
    File.open("#{PHOTO_DIR}/#{photo.original_filename}",'wb') do |file|
        file.write(photo.read)
    end
            
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html {
            render :text => 'File uploaded.'
        }
    end
end
```

Perimissions on the folder where photos would be stored is "drw-rw-rw-", owner is my user, group is also my user.

I tried to fix this by reclaiming ownership using  `chown -R user:user /path/to/photos` but it didn't work.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Are you sure `PHOTO_DIR` constant is set up properly? It looks like you are trying to open a file from the root, not from some app folder (`...rb_sysopen - /photo.jpg`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with PHOTO_DIR constant because it is setted as env variable in constants.rb file.

```
PHOTO_DIR = ENV['PHOTO']
```

When I changed env variable with the full path to the dir, everything works as expected.

```
PHOTO_DIR = '/path/to/jpg_files/'
```

It looks like env variable is not loaded in ~/.bashrc file but I tried `echo $PHOTO` and path to the photos is printed.